# Transmitting 433Mhz Message with VirtualWire to PIGPIO

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, radio-transmission

Transmitting Device: Arduino Micro with 433Mhz Transmitter via VirtualWire

Receiver: Raspberry Pi Zero with 433Mhz Receiver via PIGPIO

Transmitter/Receiver Hardware: Classic Cheap China Stuff ([Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008A4UWK6))

I am new to 433Mhz stuff and I am having problems sending a simple String: `433MHz`from the arduino to the Raspberry Pi.
My Arduino Code:

```
#include<VirtualWire.h>
int led =13;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  vw_setup(2000);
  vw_set_tx_pin(11);
}
void loop() {
  const char *msg = "433 MHz";
  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);  
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, strlen(msg));
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

I am listening to an 433Mhz signal with the Raspberry Pi Zero via the simple command: `./_433D -r10`
I tested the setup by sending signals with a normal 433 Remote and the signal shows up on the pi.

While sending via the Arduino the Pi shows nothing....
Distance should not be a problem because transmitter and receiver are next to each other .... 1-2 cm.
The transmitting Pin is 11 and the transmitter is connected to 5V from the arduino.
Is there a problem with the setup or the code? Is the communication between a Pi and an Arduino supposed to work this way or is my approach wrong?

thx

Edit: I changed the distance during testing a few times and nothing changed so I don't think it has something to do with it

Comment: It's very possible your transmitter and receiver are too close.